# Android ImageView wont clear

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-imageview, picasso

I have this url being loaded into an imageview by picasso

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    sceneUrl = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Picasso.with(this).load(sceneUrl).into(image);
```

This activity is being started from a broadcast receiver via intent...

```
                                Intent scene = new Intent( context, Image.class );
                                scene.putExtra("url", output);
                                scene.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                                scene.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                scene.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                                context.startActivity(scene);
```

Everytime i broadcast a new intent meaning a new image, the same image shows when the activity pops up.
What isn't being cleared? is it picasso or the imageview or the activity... something is stuck and is keeping the old url/image around

Answer (score 1):

```
 Picasso.with(this).load(sceneUrl).skipMemoryCache().into(image);
```

Comment: thanks..ill try it out.. how do i set a image while the url is loading?